# WPF application generate user-scoped settings in multiple folders

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, settings

I have a WPF application(test.exe) with user-scoped settings. I can see my user.config located at C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\test\test.exe_Url_raornelfbsjbaoakjkwqaipidteatrp5\1.0.0.0. But if I check out the source code (without any changes), build and run it, the settings are not loaded and I can see another user.config file generated under C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\test\test.exe_Url_vrsmziieznz0fd3n51hjhct3hgch2ex3\1.0.0.0.

How to make the application load/update/save user.config from one location ))? That is hash value should maintain unchanged

App.config specifies an user-scoped setting

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="Test.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
  <userSettings>
<Test.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="Setting" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
</Test.Properties.Settings>
```

```
// settings class which contains application specific data
public class BookSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This needs to be public in order for it to work with the .NET
    /// runtime
    /// </summary>
    [UserScopedSetting]
    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
    [DefaultSettingValue("")]
    public Dictionary<string, BookSetting> Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return (Dictionary<string, BookSetting>) this["Settings"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["Settings"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Someone has the same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ebb928f-df37-4076-9d0e-0701f3e2031f/how-is-the-user-settings-path-constructed?forum=wpf

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Joe I posted the code, but I think I have to specify the path of the user.config in either app.config or programmatically

Comment: I encountered a similar problem last week. I just decided to manually find it using `Directory.GetFiles()`, then single out the one with the most recent modification by using LINQ and `fileArray.Select(file=>File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file)).OrderByDescending(file=>file.TimeOfDay).OrderByDescending(file.Date).FirstOrDefault();`. Then I just read them manually using `XDocument`.

Comment: @Meloviz I am trying not to hack it to see if the hash value can be unchagned.